# Merging a weird html-like txt file with an Excel file

Tags: html, r, excel, merge

I got two files which I'm supposed to merge (most likely using statistical software such as R or SPSS), one of them being a normal Excel table with 3 variables (names at the top of the columns). The second one, however, was sent to me in a format I haven't seen before, a large txt file with input per case (identified with the ID variable, which I would also use to merge with the Excel file) which looks like this:

```
<organizations>
<organization id="B0101">
<type1>E</type1>
<type2>v</type2>
<name>International Association for Official Statistics</name>
<acronym>IAOS</acronym>
<country_first_address>not known</country_first_address>
<city_first_address>not known</city_first_address>
<countries_in_which_members_located>not known</countries_in_which_members_located>
<subject_headings>Government; Statistics</subject_headings>
<foundation_year>1985</foundation_year>
<history>[[History]] Founded 1985, Amsterdam (Netherlands), at 45th Session of #A2590, as a specialized section of ISI. Absorbed, 1989, #D1316, which had been set up 22 Oct 1958, Geneva (Switzerland), following recommendations of ISI, as [International Association of Municipal Statisticians -- Association internationale de statisticiens municipaux]. </history>
<history_relations>#A2590; #D1316</history_relations>
<consultative_status>none known</consultative_status>
<igo_relations>none known</igo_relations>
<ngo_relations>#E1209; #M4975; #D1976; #E2125; #E3673; #D2578; #M0084</ngo_relations>
<member_organizations>none known</member_organizations>
</organization>

<organization id="B8500">
<type1>B</type1>
<type2>y</type2>
<name>World Blind Union</name>
<acronym>WBU</acronym>
<country_first_address>Canada</country_first_address>
<city_first_address>Toronto</city_first_address>
<countries_in_which_members_located>Algeria; Angola; Benin; Burkina Faso; Burundi; Cameroon; Cape Verde; Central African Rep; Chad; Congo Brazzaville; Congo DR; Côte d'Ivoire; Djibouti; Egypt; Equatorial Guinea; Eritrea; Ethiopia; Gabon; Gambia; Ghana; Guinea; Guinea-Bissau; Kenya; Lesotho; Liberia; Libyan AJ; Madagascar; Malawi; Mali; Mauritania; Mauritius; Morocco; Mozambique; Namibia; Niger; Nigeria; Rwanda; Sao Tomé-Principe; Senegal; Seychelles; Sierra Leone; Somalia; South Africa; South Sudan; Sudan; Swaziland; Tanzania UR; Togo; Tunisia; Uganda; Zambia; Zimbabwe; Anguilla; Antigua-Barbuda; Argentina; Bahamas; Barbados; Belize; Bolivia; Brazil; Canada; Chile; Colombia; Costa Rica; Cuba; Dominica; Dominican Rep; Ecuador; El Salvador; Grenada; Guatemala; Guyana; Haiti; Honduras; Jamaica; Martinique; Mexico; Montserrat; Nicaragua; Panama; Paraguay; Peru; St Kitts-Nevis; St Lucia; St Vincent-Grenadines; Trinidad-Tobago; Turks-Caicos; Uruguay; USA; Venezuela; Virgin Is UK; Afghanistan; Bahrain; Bangladesh; Brunei Darussalam; Cambodia; China; Hong Kong; India; Indonesia; Iraq; Israel; Japan; Jordan; Kazakhstan; Korea Rep; Kuwait; Kyrgyzstan; Laos; Lebanon; Macau; Malaysia; Mongolia; Myanmar; Nepal; Pakistan; Philippines; Qatar; Singapore; Sri Lanka; Syrian AR; Taiwan; Tajikistan; Thailand; Timor-Leste; Turkmenistan; United Arab Emirates; Uzbekistan; Vietnam; Yemen; Australia; Fiji; New Zealand; Tonga; Albania; Armenia; Austria; Azerbaijan; Belarus; Belgium; Bosnia-Herzegovina; Bulgaria; Croatia; Cyprus; Czech Rep; Denmark; Estonia; Finland; France; Georgia; Germany; Greece; Hungary; Iceland; Ireland; Italy; Latvia; Lithuania; Luxembourg; Macedonia; Malta; Moldova; Montenegro; Netherlands; Norway; Poland; Portugal; Romania; Russia; Serbia; Slovakia; Slovenia; Spain; Sweden; Switzerland; Turkey; UK; Ukraine;</countries_in_which_members_located>
<subject_headings>Blind, Visually Impaired</subject_headings>
<foundation_year>1984</foundation_year>
<history>[[History]] Founded 26 Oct 1984, Riyadh (Saudi Arabia), as one united world body composed of representatives of national associations of the blind and agencies serving the blind, successor body to both #B3499, set up 20 July 1951, Paris (France), and #B2024, formed in Aug 1964, New York NY (USA). Constitution adopted 26 Oct 1984; amended at: 3rd General Assembly, 2-6 Nov 1992, Cairo (Egypt); 26-30 Aug 1996, Toronto (Canada); 20-24 Nov 2000, Melbourne (Australia); 22-26 Nov 2004, Cape Town (South Africa); 18-22 Aug 2008, Geneva (Switzerland); 12-16 Nov 2012, Bangkok (Thailand). Registered in accordance with French law, 20 Dec 1984, Paris and again 20 Dec 2004, Paris. Incorporated in Canada as not-share-capital not-for-profit corporation, 16 Mar 2007. </history>
<history_relations>#B3499; #B2024</history_relations>
<consultative_status>#E3377; #B2183; #B3548; #B0971; #F3380; #B3635</consultative_status>
<igo_relations>#E7552; #F1393; #A3375; #B3408</igo_relations>
<ngo_relations>#E0409; #E6422; #J5215; #F5821; #C1224; #D5392; #F6792; #A1945; #B2314; #D1758; #F5810; #D1612; #J0357; #D1038; #G6537; #B2221; #B0094; #B3536; #D7556</ngo_relations>
<member_organizations>#F6063; #F4959; #J1979; #C1224; #B0094; #D5392; #A1945; #D2362; #F2936; #J4730; #F3167; #D8743; #F1898; #D0043; #G0853</member_organizations>
</organization>
```

Any help would be appreciated - what type of file this is and how to transform it into a manageable table?

Comment: Looks like xml. I will have a go at trying to read it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data is XML. I copied your sample data, pasted it into a blank file, and saved it as `sample.xml`. I made sure to add in a line with `</organizations>` at the very end (line 37 in your sample), to close off that tag.

Then I followed the instructions [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-the-web-for-beginners-part-ii-xml-in-r/) to read it in:

```
library(XML)
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(file = "sample.xml")
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile)
orgs <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
orgs_df <- data.frame(t(orgs),row.names=NULL)
```

This returns a dataframe `orgs_df` with 2 obs. of 15 variables. I presume you can now go ahead and merge this with your Excel file as you please.

Comment: Glad it's worked for you @AgataUtrecht You will probably need to do a bit more tidying of your data after reading it in though.